# ES6 Difference between arrow function and method definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

What is the difference between next functions

```
module.exports = utils.Backbone.View.extend({
    handler: () => {
       console.log(this);
    } 
});
```

and

```
module.exports = utils.Backbone.View.extend({
    handler() {
       console.log(this);
    } 
});
```

Why in first case `this === window`?

Comment: That is the difference. Arrow function doesn't bind `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because arrow functions do not create their own this context, so `this` has the original value from the enclosing context.

In your case, the enclosing context is the global context so `this` in the arrow function is `window`.

```
const obj = {
  handler: () => {
    // `this` points to the context outside of this function, 
    // which is the global context so `this === window`
  }
}
```

On the other hand, context for regular functions is dynamic and when such function is invoked as a method on an object, `this` points to the method's owning object.

```
const obj = {
  handler() {
    // `this` points to `obj` as its context, `this === obj`
  }
}
```

The above syntax uses [ES6 method shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). It is functionally equivalent to:

```
const obj = {
  handler: function handler() {
    // `this` points to `obj` as its context, `this === obj`
  }
}
```

Comment: perfectly clear, thank you!